# Cant get included file to connect to database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I must be missing something simple but I don't see it. The following code works great.

```
<?php
$res = mysql_connect("localhost", "newuser", "");
mysql_select_db("supplydb");
function filter($data)
{
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    return $data;
}
error_reporting(0);

require("../codebase/grid_connector.php");

$mask5 = filter($_GET["var1"]);

//Get Category ID
$cat    = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM submissions WHERE submissions.submission_id='$mask5'");
$rows   = mysql_fetch_array($cat, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$array  = filter($rows['category']);
//Get Manufactuer ID
$man    = mysql_query("SELECT manufacturer_id FROM submissions WHERE submissions.submission_id='$mask5'");
$arows  = mysql_fetch_array($man, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$array1 = filter($arows['manufacturer_id']);
function formatting($row)
{
    $data = $row->get_value("fda_approved");
    if ($data == 1)
        $row->set_value("fda_approved", Yes);
    else
        $row->set_value("fda_approved", No);
}
$gridConn = new GridConnector($res, "MySQL");

function myUpdate($action)
{
    $data6 = $action->get_id();
    $cat_id = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM submissions WHERE submissions.submission_id ='{$data6}'") or die("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());
    $rows56   = mysql_fetch_array($cat_id, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $array    = filter($rows56['category']);
    $status   = $action->get_value("approval_status");
    $gridConn = new GridConnector($res, "MySQL");
    mysql_query("UPDATE submissions SET approval_status='{$status}' WHERE submissions.submission_id='{$data6}'") or die("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());
    $action->success;
 }
$gridConn->event->attach("beforeUpdate", "myUpdate"); 
$gridConn->event->attach("beforeRender", "formatting");
$gridConn->render_sql("SELECT * FROM submissions JOIN products ON products.product_id = submissions.product_id and submissions.category='$array' and submissions.manufacturer_id='$array1' and submissions.approval_status='0'", "submission_id", "item_number,description,list_price,sugg_price,quantity_per_unit,fda_approved,gpo_contract_number, approval_status");
?>
```

This code does not

```
<?php
require("../site_globals/dbc_simple.php");
//$res = mysql_connect("localhost", "newuser", "");
//mysql_select_db("supplydb");
error_reporting(0);
require("../codebase/grid_connector.php");
$mask5 = filter($_GET["var1"]);
//Get Category ID
$cat    = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM submissions WHERE submissions.submission_id='$mask5'");
$rows   = mysql_fetch_array($cat, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$array  = filter($rows['category']);
//Get Manufactuer ID
$man    = mysql_query("SELECT manufacturer_id FROM submissions WHERE submissions.submission_id='$mask5'");
$arows  = mysql_fetch_array($man, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$array1 = filter($arows['manufacturer_id']);
function formatting($row)
{
    $data = $row->get_value("fda_approved");
    if ($data == 1)
        $row->set_value("fda_approved", Yes);
    else
        $row->set_value("fda_approved", No);
}
$gridConn = new GridConnector($res, "MySQL");

function myUpdate($action)
{
    $data6 = $action->get_id();
    $cat_id = mysql_query("SELECT category FROM submissions WHERE submissions.submission_id ='{$data6}'") or die("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());
    $rows56   = mysql_fetch_array($cat_id, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        $array    = filter($rows56['category']);
    $status   = $action->get_value("approval_status");
    $gridConn = new GridConnector($res, "MySQL");
    mysql_query("UPDATE submissions SET approval_status='{$status}' WHERE submissions.submission_id='{$data6}'") or die("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());
    $action->success;
 }
$gridConn->event->attach("beforeUpdate", "myUpdate"); 
$gridConn->event->attach("beforeRender", "formatting");
$gridConn->render_sql("SELECT * FROM submissions JOIN products ON products.product_id = submissions.product_id and submissions.category='$array' and submissions.manufacturer_id='$array1' and submissions.approval_status='0'", "submission_id", "item_number,description,list_price,sugg_price,quantity_per_unit,fda_approved,gpo_contract_number, approval_status");
?>
```

The only difference is the include file at the top and all the include file is is:

```
<?php
$res = mysql_connect("localhost", "newuser", "");
mysql_select_db("supplydb");
?>
```

Im fairly new to php but this seems simple and I'm not sure what is getting lost in translation. This works fine on other pages by the way so it must have something to do with the $gridConn = new GridConnector($res, "MySQL"); but I dont know enough to see what. I'm using the DHTMLX javascript library. Could it have something to do with that? Ive tried everything here. Ideas?

Comment: are you sure your include path is correct? Also you are turning off error reporting. It might be helpful to turn it back on in order to find the problem.

Comment: Im getting: XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Location: http://localhost/site_hospital01/pop_category_connect_denied.php
Line Number 1, Column 2:

Comment: Is there some specific requirement with XML and include files. I don't have any whitespace in either file.

Comment: Don't assume database calls succeeded. One little glitch and your entire script blows up. you shoul have AT MINIMUM `mysql_whatever(...) or die(mysql_error())` everywhere you do a DB operation.

Comment: Im definitely getting a connection. I have the same problem as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387514/xml-parsing-error-xml-or-text-declaration-not-at-start-of-entity-in-php) but nobody posted the answer so I guess I'm on my own to figure out where the whitespace is. Its not obvious I can tell you that. My include file is as simple as it gets. Truly stumped on why it would cause an xml error vs placing connection directly in script.

Comment: can you verify that $res exists after you require the file? try var_dump($res); after the require to see if it is set. Also about the XML error from the source you posted I can't make any sense out of it.

Answer (score 0):

> Im getting: XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity Location

Problem is not in the database connection itself, it works correctly and generates data, but result xml corrupted, because some output was started before connector's code.

Check ../site_globals/dbc_simple.php - probably it have some whitespaces|newlines after closing "?>" tag - delete them and it will fix the problem.

Such whitespaces|newlines will not cause harm for HTML pages, but for XML data any extra char at start of document can cause a problem.